# How to use php variable in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Hi I am trying to make code for array in php but didn't get any solution please help me

```
{ if !in_array($productgroup.gid,array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,{php}echo $cid;{/php})) }

<option value="{$productgroup.gid}"{if $gid eq $productgroup.gid} selected="selected"{/if}>{$productgroup.name}</option>

{/if}
```

Comment: Thats basically correct. Did you assign the variable to the template?

Comment: Actually variable,I get from get method from url on that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create array in PHP? Then:

**PHP**

```
$smarty->assign('cid', array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77));
```

**Smarty**

```
{ if !in_array($productgroup.gid, $cid) }
    ...
{/if}
```

Or you want add dynamic element in your array? Then:

**PHP**

```
$smarty->assign('cid', $some_number);
```

**Smarty**

```
{ if !in_array($productgroup.gid,array(69,68,27,31,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,$cid)) }
    ...
{/if}
```